# Chrome drag and drop issues in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ckeditor

Hello i am having issue in chrome i have ckeditor like this
[image]

when i do **drag and drop** of images into a **ckeditor** particulary in **Mozilla** its working fine user side also its displaying but in chrome its not chrome shows images and it leaves current page this issue i am facing from many times images pasting not working in chrome with ckeditor what should i do?

also when i see images in ie only half image is shown this is **base32  problem** so its basically browser problem that ie can not display chars upto 64 base so any idea to solve this ?

i am stuck in ckeditor

Comment: Where are you dragging it from? CKFinder? Desktop file browse? Word? What do you need the image src to point to; a local file on computer or an uploaded file? Do you need to prevent drops? The base issue is a separate problem, do you have a link to show the problem? Much more information is required to solve this.

Comment: I am just dragging it from my desktop to editor if can provide some tips for handling images in ckeditor that's also ok

Answer (score 0):

You can refer on this blog http://alfonsoml.blogspot.nl/2012/06/drag-and-drop-uploads-in-ckeditor.html. I hope this would help you. :)

Comment: Sorry about my late reply. I purchased the plugin http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/p/simpleuploads-plugin-for-ckeditor.html, added it inside my ckeditor plugin folder and then inserted config.extraPlugins = 'simpleuploads'; in my config.js file. If you setup everything like this you may need to clear your chache. :D